# how to check popup is closed when X button is clicked on the page

Tags: c#, asp.net, popup

I am redirecting a popup in asp.net(not through javascript). My requirement is, when the user closes the popup, I need to perform some action on the main page. How could I do this in asp.net.

This is my code for redirecting,

```
if (Request.QueryString["DESC"].ToString() == "AAA")
{
    Response.Redirect("Edit.aspx"','popup', 'statusbar=no,toolbar=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=yes,resizable=no,location=no,height=600,width=800');");
}
```

In Edit.aspx,

```
protected void Page_Unload(object sender,EventArgs e)
{
 //This is loading when page is loaded. This did not work when page is closed.
}
```

Please suggest me any method.
Assume that now the Edit.aspx popup is opened. When it is closed I want to perform some other functionality.

I tried with Page_Unload event. But this is being called when the popup is loaded and not when unloaded.

Comment: Show your codes please

Comment: I'm assuming the popup should have an on close event? Either way we need some code.

Comment: @Shivan,Placed my code in the above. Please find it!!

Comment: Possible using JavaScript and jQuery but I don't think so in asp.net.  Is that acceptable for you?

Comment: @philip, yes please. Any answer is accepted. Either javascript or asp.net but not jquery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can open child window from parent using javascript as below:-

```
window.open('Child.htm','');
window.myfunction = function(){

}
```

Now when user clicks on close button of child window you can call your javascript function defined in parent page or execute enent referring to event of parent page :-

```
window.onunload = function (e) {
    opener.myfunction (); //or
    opener.document.getElementById('someid').innerHTML = 'update content of parent window';
};
```

But if you want to do it in asp.net(without javascript) you can follow below steps:-

1)`Response.Redirect(DestinationPage.aspx)`

2)Do manipulation on your DestinationPage nad redirect back to SourcePage with an 
identifier in URL `Response.Redirect(SourcePage.aspx?operation=myoperation)`

3)Read value of `operation` from `QueryString` and do the operation as needed.